# Unable to pass a variable to a scene in spritekit in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm currently having trouble with passing variables to a scene in spritekit (swift). In android when moving to a different activity, I just set the parameter to the Intent and simply get the variable. But since I'm new to spritekit and swift, i find it difficult. Is there a clear way to pass a variable to the scene ? I have a sample code below that I tested but did not work.

```
class GameSKView: SKView {

    var mylevel = 0

}

//Inside my main GameScen 
let gameView = self.view as GameSKView
sample.text = "my level is :\(gameView.mylevel)"
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try to set `gameView.myLevel`?

Comment: I get the error  "Could not cast value of type 'SKView' (0x3af52ce8) to 'Sample.GameSKView' (0x85138)."

Comment: Well, then there is nothing wrong with accessing your property but instead you try to cash self.view to a type of class that it is not :) Fix that problem and you should be good... If you try my answer, your code doesn't at least crash anymore in that scenario because it doesn't jump inside the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

In order to use the custom SKView, I have done the following procedures.

1. Open the Idenity inspector in the Main.storyboard
2. Replace the [SKView] inside the  Custom Class with your [customSKView]
   , In my case GameSKView
3. Save. That was all I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class GameSKView: SKView {

    internal var mylevel = 0

}
```

And inside you main game scene

```
if let gameView = self.view as GameSKView {
    sample.text = "my level is :\(gameView!.mylevel)"
}
```